# Select all elements in between two tags of the same type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could i select all the elements between two tags of the same type using javascript or jquery?

For examle if i had:

```
<h1></h1>
<h2><h2>
<li1></li1>
<li2></li3>
<li3></li4>
<h2></h2>
```

How could i get all the `<li>`?

I tried using this `$units=$(this).nextuntil("h2");` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('h2:first').nextUntil('h2:last');
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/63/

This of course only works in this particular example. In a more complex markup, you would probably need to be more specific. Like `$('h2:eq(2)')` or others pseudo-selectors.