# Jsoup: Extract all HTML between two blocks in CSS-less HTML

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

What would be an optimal way, using Jsoup, to extract all HTML (either to a String, Document or Elements) between two blocks that conform to this pattern:

```
<strong>
 {any HTML could appear here, except for a <strong> pair}
</strong>

 ...
 {This is the HTML I need to extract. 
  any HTML could appear here, except for a <strong> pair}
 ... 

<strong>
 {any HTML could appear here, except for a <strong> pair}
</strong>
```

Using a regex this could be simple, if I apply it on the entire body.html():

```
(<strong>.+</strong>)(.+)(<strong>.+</strong>)
                       ^
                       +----- There I have my HTML content
```

But as I learned from a [similar challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290066/extract-text-between-two-hr-tags-in-css-less-html/7290241#7290241), performance could be improved (even if the code is slightly longer) if I use an already Jsoup-parsed DOM -- except that this time neither `Element.nextSibling()` nor `Element.nextElementSibling()` can come to the rescue.

I searched for something like jQuery's [nextUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724551/select-all-elements-in-between-two-tags-of-the-same-type) in Jsoup, for example, but couldn't really find something similar.

Is it possible to come up with something better than the above regex-based approach?

Comment: Does it matter if the HTML extracted from the DOM is different to the original string? Because often HTML cleaners like jsoup can alter (fix) the DOM, and therefore a subsequent DOM->HTML conversion will result in a string that differs to your original. In these cases, a regexp might be safer.

Comment: Why don't you simply use jsoup's select method to extract all <strong> elements and then throw away the first and the last one?

Comment: What about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534456/jsoup-how-to-get-all-html-between-2-header-tags

Comment: are the two <strong> siblings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's faster but maybe something like this will work:

```
Elements strongs = doc.select("strong");
Element f = strongs.first();
Element l = strongs.last();
Elements siblings = f.siblingElements();
List<Element> result = siblings.subList(siblings.firstIndexOf(f) + 1,siblings.lastIndexOf(l));
```